# Retrieving post meta with REST API using \register_meta()

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

WordPress Codex suggests [two ways](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/) of adding post meta to the response. I'm trying to achieve this with [register_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_meta) since it kinda seems to be the correct way to me.

**PROBLEM**:

*meta* field in the response remains empty when I use [register_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_meta) although *show_in_rest* is set to true.

**SOLUTION**:

Thanks to [Allan Fuller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6025448/alan-fuller), who pointed out, that the **$object_type** parameter (the first one in **register_meta()** function should be *post* and not the post type. This is also mentioned in the [comments section of the new code reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_meta/#user-contributed-notes)

---

**Description before solution**

Here how am I doing this:

Step 1: 
call from functions.php:

```
\add_action('init', [$this, 'init'], 10);
```

Step 2:
register custom post type in the init function:

```
\register_post_type(
            CompanyPostType::POST_TYPE_NAME,
            [
                'labels' => [
                    'name' => __('Companies'),
                    'singular_name' => __('Company')
                ],
                'public' => true,
                'show_in_rest' => true,
                'rest_base' => CompanyPostType::REST_BASE,
                'has_archive' => false,
                'rewrite' => false,
                'supports' => [
                    'custom-fields',
                    'revisions'
                ]
            ]
        );
```

Step 3 - <s>profit</s>:
register meta for the custom post type in the init function

```
$meta = [
     'key' => CompanyPostType::META_NAME,
     'description' => 'Name of the company',
     'type' => 'string'                    
],
\register_meta(CompanyPostType::POST_TYPE_NAME, $meta['key'],
                [
                    'show_in_rest' => true,
                    'single' => true,
                    'type' => $meta['type'],
                    'description' => $meta['description'],
                ]
            );
```

The meta field is still remains empty in the response. If I however use the second way also suggested in the codex ([register_rest_field()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_field/)) in the same init hook:

```
\add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
            \register_rest_field( CompanyPostType::POST_TYPE_NAME, CompanyPostType::META_NAME, array(
                'get_callback' => function($params ) {
                    $meta = \get_post_meta( $params['id'],  CompanyPostType::META_NAME, true);
                    return (string) $meta;
                },
            ) );
        } );
```

then the field with its value appears in the response. What am I missing?

Since I'm using a custom post type, it may be worth looking at this part of code as well. As stated in the codex, when registering it I set ‘supports’ => [‘custom-fields’] so that custom fields appear in the rest response. The whole looks like this:

```
        return \register_post_type(
            self::POST_TYPE_NAME,
            [
                'labels' => [
                    'name' => __('Companies'),
                    'singular_name' => __('Company')
                ],
                'public' => true,
                'show_in_rest' => true,
                'rest_base' => self::REST_BASE,
                'has_archive' => false,
                'rewrite' => false,
                'supports' => [
                    'title',
                    'custom-fields',
                    'revisions'
                ]
            ]
        );
```

**EDIT:**

I tried, as suggested by [Allan Fuller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6025448/alan-fuller) in his [blog post](http://badlywired.com/2018/01/getting-post-meta-via-wordpress-rest-api/), to put **\register_meta()** in **rest_api_init** hook, but it has no effect on meta in the response.

Comment: change CompanyPostType::POST_TYPE_NAME  to 'post' as the object type is post not the CPT name

Comment: Thanks, that was it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `register_meta` to work, you have to explicitly hook it to `rest_api_init`
so for your example

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_posts_meta_field' ); 
function register_posts_meta_field() {   
  register_meta('post', $meta['key'],
            [
                'show_in_rest' => true,
                'single' => true,
                'type' => $meta['type'],
                'description' => $meta['description'],
            ]
        );
}
```

The above is untested but see working plugin version of code here http://badlywired.com/2018/01/getting-post-meta-via-wordpress-rest-api/

The object type needs to be 'post' to the custom post type name

see https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_meta

first argument is object_type - valid object types are predefined by wordpress and CPT is a type of post

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually tried it out yesterday, as I've seen it in your post, but it has no affect. Have you tried it with the [latest stable WordPress version](https://wordpress.org/wordpress-4.9.4.zip)? If you confirm, that this approach still work, then it has do something with my environment I guess...

Comment: see my edits $object_type needs to be 'post' not the cpt name
this applies to your original code too ( and maybe you don't need to hook rest_api_init, I do that to force when the meta hasn't been defined by a plugin )

Comment: Nice! That did the trick! Actually now I also found this in the comments of the [new code reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_meta/#user-contributed-notes). Thank you for your time!

Comment: It is important to note that `custom-fields` should be set on the post type for this to work, this should be stated prominently.